# How do you use build labels in publishers in cruisecontrol?

Tags: mercurial, build-process, build-automation, cruisecontrol

I have this section in my CruiseControl `config.xml` file:

```
<publishers>
   <onsuccess>
        <artifactspublisher dest="artifacts/${project.name}" file="projects/${project.name}/fred"/>
        <execute command="hg -R hg-succeeded/${project.name} pull"/>
        <execute command="hg -R hg-succeeded/${project.name} tag -l build-${label} -r tip"/>
    </onsuccess>
</publishers>
```

I'm getting tags that look like `build-${label}`.  The `${label}` part isn't being replaced by the build label like I expect.  I'm expecting something like `build.1` to show up in place of `${label}`.  How do I make this happen?

I do have the default labelincrementer configured with a `<labelincrementer />` tag in my project.

Also, the CruiseControl documentation is absolutely awful.  Is there better documentation anywhere?

Comment: I'm setting a bounty on this since I didn't really get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody has answered this, so I will put this answer here so I can select it sometime tomorrow and lose the bounty.  *sigh*

My answer is to use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), since it looks like CruiseControl has really fallen off doing any useful development and has switched to largely working on the .NET version which I have no interest in.  Though if anyone knows how to do it in CruiseControl I'm still all ears.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `${label}` with something like a SVN revision number, you can build a label incrementer plugin - see http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Build/cruisecontrol/net/sourceforge/cruisecontrol/labelincrementers/SVNLabelIncrementer.java.htm for an example.

This is built into a jar, and placed in the CruiseControl\lib directory.

In your CC config, you'd define this plugin by declaring:

```
<project ...>
  <plugin name="labelincrementer" class="my.subclass.of.LabelIncrementer" />
  <labelincrementer />
  ...
</project>
```

You can add any attributes you like inside your `<labelincrementer ... />` tag; they'll be injected into an instance of your `LabelIncrementer` subclass by `setXXX` methods.

Comment: Well, that's almost what I want.  What I really want is a label that contains the CruiseControl build number, which I believe it already maintains.  *sigh*  I know Java, but I despise it.  And CruiseControl seems very SVN centered too.  It's really irritating.  But it's the only tool that does what I want.  :-(  It looks like maybe I'm going to have to dive into the code for the default label incrementer and figure out which tag it sets.

Comment: There's always the DefaultLabelIncrementer. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Build/cruisecontrol/net/sourceforge/cruisecontrol/labelincrementers/DefaultLabelIncrementer.java.htm

Comment: @Matt Gumbley - That's true, and it's what I'm using.  But what attribute does it set?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I think it will use a default label of "build.1" - the 1 being incremented with the build number. I think you can override this with <labelincrementer defaultLabel="ccnum.1"/> - basically, any text, followed by ., then some integer. [from looking at the source; haven't checked the docs, I suspect they may not help :-( ]

Comment: @Matt Gumbley - "build.1" is indeed the value of the label.  But how do you get that value to substitute inside of a publisher?

Comment: If you're running an ant script within your CC <project...>, via the ant task, the ant script may be able to pick it up via the "${label}" variable. Some more useful info found here: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/gettingstartedsourcedist.html#Create_a_Delegating_Build_Script

Comment: I think I'm going to take eclipse to CC and figure out how in the heck property substitution is done.

Comment: I know it's not helping directly with the problem, but must it be CruiseControl? I've found Hudson to be a far better CI system.

Comment: @Matt Gumbley - It does not have to be CC.  I figured there was little difference between one Java-based CI system and another.  But I absolutely __detest__ Java, so its hard for me to gauge relative quality.  :-)  Unfortunately BuiltBot with its emphasis on multiple platforms and its bizarre waterfall diagram is a poor fit.